# How can I remove the default notification popup on Android 13 when launching my Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

We are trying to suppress the default notification popup which comes after the app is launched by a new user. From Android 13 (API level 33) onwards, apps now have the ability to display a prompt where users can decide if they want to grant an app permission to show notifications. how can remove this popup?

how can remove this popup?